# SELECT FOR UPDATE seems not to work in a PL/SQL-driven Testcase with Oracle 12.1/19.3

Tags: oracle, plsql, locking

I intended to create a simple load test :

- An ACCOUNT TABLE
- A Procedure Updating the Account Balance
- A Start-Script using Oracle dbms_scheduler to run the procedure in parallel.

Each procedure Call covers the Account_ID 1-16 and increments the Account Balance 500 times.
So at the end the Account Balance is 500. For the test-case I run 4 concurrent background jobs per Account ID to increment the Account Balance, **I would expect 2000 for each Account ID** **but the results are in randomly a range of 1850 till 1950**; I use SELECT for UPDATE to lock the Account ID to be updated, but it does not work. Any ideas?

The table creation :

```
DROP TABLE ACCOUNTS;
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS ( ACC_ID INTEGER NOT NULL , ACC_BALANCE NUMBER (9,3) DEFAULT 0  NOT NULL , START_TIME TIMESTAMP, END_TIME TIMESTAMP);
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT ACCOUNTS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ACC_ID);


INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS SELECT ROWNUM , 0 , NULL, NULL FROM DBA_USERS DT WHERE ROWNUM <= 16;
COMMIT WORK;
```

The Procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Paccount_Test(p_Acc_Id     IN INTEGER
                                         ,p_Incr       IN NUMBER
                                         ,p_Num_Incr   IN INTEGER
                                         ,p_Work_Loops IN INTEGER) IS
    Xx            INTEGER := 0;
    l_Acc_Balance Accounts.Acc_Balance%TYPE;
BEGIN

    UPDATE Accounts SET Acc_Balance = 0.0, Start_Time = Systimestamp, End_Time = NULL WHERE Acc_Id = p_Acc_Id;
    COMMIT WORK;

    FOR Nloops IN 1 .. p_Num_Incr LOOP
        SELECT Acc_Balance INTO l_Acc_Balance FROM Accounts WHERE Acc_Id = p_Acc_Id FOR UPDATE;
    
        -- Amoount of work ...
        FOR Ii IN 1 .. p_Work_Loops LOOP
            Xx := Xx + 1;
        END LOOP;
    
        UPDATE Accounts SET Acc_Balance = Acc_Balance + p_Incr WHERE Acc_Id = p_Acc_Id;
        COMMIT WORK;
    END LOOP;

    UPDATE Accounts SET End_Time = Systimestamp WHERE Acc_Id = p_Acc_Id;
    COMMIT WORK;

END Paccount_Test;
```

The Starter Script for 64 Processes, ...

```
BEGIN
    FOR Acc_Id IN 1 .. 64 LOOP
        Dbms_Scheduler.Create_Job(Job_Name   => 'One_Time_Job' || Acc_Id
                                 ,Job_Type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
                                 ,Job_Action => 'begin paccount_test (p_acc_id => ' || (mod(Acc_Id,16)+1) ||
                                                ', p_incr => 1, p_num_incr => 500, p_work_loops => 400000); end;'
                                 ,Start_Date => SYSDATE
                                 ,Enabled    => TRUE
                                 ,Auto_Drop  => TRUE
                                 ,Comments   => 'one-time job');
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Ich checked DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG, but did not see any error, also in V$session 64 Background processes were active.

Example Output of SELECT query :

```
ACC_ID ACC_BALANCE
1      1932,000
2      1900,000
3      1902,000
4      1883,000
5      1910,000
6      1939,000
7      1920,000
8      1910,000
9      1865,000
10     1920,000
11     1916,000
12     1888,000
13     1896,000
14     1909,000
15     1918,000
16     1935,000
```

Comment: `but the results are in randomly a range of 1850 till 1950`. where did you check this ?

Comment: It's the result of SELECT from the ACCOUNT table after all background jobs finished, I expected 2000 for every account id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simulated the issue and the problem is the `update statement` at the beginning and before `increment loop` starts which also updates the `acc_balance` to `0` (it could happen for any record which has no lock at this very time and thus we see the value different than expected `2000`) which is causing the issue here and for me too missed at first glance.

We also can make the above `update` with `for update` which I didn't try and could solve the problem but I don't think we need to update the `acc_balance` here and just remove it from the `update` clause to only update `Start_Time` and `End_Time`.

```
UPDATE Accounts 
   SET Start_Time = Systimestamp
     , End_Time = NULL 
 WHERE Acc_Id = p_Acc_Id;
```

And if at all it is a `load test` we always can update the value back to `0` before you actually start the load test otherwise need to find another way to update automatically.

I would wait for your feedback and see if it solves your issue and doesn't require any further modification

Comment: Wow !!! I think this is the issue !!! Thanks a lot!
I think you pointed it out, the initialization may occur only once per ACC_ID in parallel mode. As the background sessions do not start at the same time an already made increment is set back to 0 again! So the init must be done outside of the procedure.

Comment: @THX1188, great ...I would request to accept the answer if it resolved your issue. Cheers!!!

Comment: `BEGIN
    UPDATE Accounts Acc SET Acc.Acc_Balance = 0, Acc.Start_Time = Systimestamp, Acc.End_Time = NULL;
    COMMIT WORK;

    FOR Run_Id IN 1 .. 64 LOOP`

I put the initialization out of the procedure into the start-script , now the results work out as expected .

Comment: Yes you are right and this completes the answer as well :). Thanks.